# Button is not visible in Listview

Tags: html, listview

Button is not showing in the container specially in the list division.
What I've done wrong?

here my code:

```
<body>
       <h2>Discussions
       </h2>
       <div class="container" id = "form-container">
           All Discussions
           <div class="list-group" style="margin-top: 3%">
               <li class="list-group-item" >
                   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">{{discussion.UserID}}</span> <br>
                   {{ discussion.Query }}
               </li>
               <li class="list-group-item"  >
                   <textarea id = "query" name = "query" ng-model = "query" class = "form-control" placeholder="here"/>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
               </li>

           </div>
           <button type="button" >Close</button>
       </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: <body>
    <h2>Discussions</h2>
    <div class="container" id = "form-container">
        All Discussions
        <div class="list-group" style="margin-top: 3%">
            
            <li class="list-group-item"  >
                <textarea id = "query" name = "query" ng-model = "query" class = "form-control" placeholder="here"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
            </li>

        </div>
        <button type="button" >Close</button>
    </div>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

Textarea is not a self-closing tag. It should be re-written as

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

So, close the textarea tag, you will be able to see the button.

```
<body>
       <h2>Discussions
       </h2>
       <div class="container" id = "form-container">
           All Discussions
           <div class="list-group" style="margin-top: 3%">
               <li class="list-group-item" >
                   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right">{{discussion.UserID}}</span> <br>
                   {{ discussion.Query }}
               </li>
               <li class="list-group-item"  >
                   **<textarea id = "query" name = "query" ng-model = "query" class = "form-control" placeholder="here"></textarea>**
               </li>
               <li>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
               </li>

           </div>
           <button type="button" >Close</button>
       </div> 
</body>
```